# getopt giving -1 as return value

Tags: c, getopt

I am trying to see how getopts work. I wrote the code below but not sure what I am doing wrong. Please point me :

```
#include<unistd.h>
.. 
..
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int ch=0;
   while((ch=getopt(argc, argv, "ltR:")!=-1) // 0 here was by mistake. Changed to -1
    {  
      printf("%d",ch); //This prints -1 
       switch(ch)
               {
                 case 'l':
                 printf("l");
                 break;
                 case 't':
                 printf("t");
                 break;
                 case 'R':
                 printf("R");
                 break;
                }
    }
   return 0;
 }

 $ ./a.out -ltR 
 $ -1
 $ ./a.out -l 
 $ -1
```

May be I am doing a really mistake or missing out on some aspect of my understanding of getopt.

Made changes but still gives the same result:(

Thanks, 
Faizan

Comment: That code also has a problem with the brackets on the while loop.  Can you paste your actual bit of code because that a) doesn't compile and b) might give a clue to your actual problem.

Comment: oh.. thats on a different machine on which I do not have internet access.. thats why had to type.. comparing both but not noticing any difference in the while loops.. checking once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your while expression should be

```
while((ch=getopt(argc, argv, "ltR")!=-1)
{..}
```

and the option should end with ':'

```
while((ch=getopt(argc, argv, "ltR:")!=-1)
{..}
```

or two ':' if switch is optional.

Comment: That 0 was by mistake. Orignally I had -1 but while typing here i made it 0. Also added "ltR:" but gives same results

Answer (score 1):

From the man page -1 indicates that all the arguments have been done, rather than 0 as you appear to be checking for.

```
man 3 getopt
```

> If  an  option  was successfully found, then getopt() returns the option character.  If all command-line options have been parsed, then getopt() returns -1.

The code in your question doesn't parse out of the box so it doesn't appear to be a proper copy paste which makes spotting the error a lot harder.  The brackets on the while loop might be the cause of your issue but it's hard to tell.  If I copy paste your example and correct the bracket issue the code works as you expect it to.

Comment: If i am passing arguments then it should not be -1 is that right? running it as ./a.out -l but still gives -1

Comment: Right Colin..it was copy mistake error here and in the actual program there was a mistake too. Corrected brackets and it worked. Thank you